# TFS 2013 : TF400975: Failed to grant TFS Job Agent permissions to start database backups on SQL Server

Tags: backup, backups

I couldn't find any documentation on this error. I've inherited TFS server administration and gotten this error message when configuring scheduled backup: TFS 2013 Update 2

"TF400975: Failed to grant TFS Job Agent permissions to start database backups on SQL Server xxxxxx"

TY in advance

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. Try the DBA site.

Comment: Thanks. Can you post the exact URL? Ty

Comment: Check the account used by 'Visual Studio Team Foundation Background Job Agent' windows service (check 'Log On' tab in the properties dialog for that service). Does this account have any permissions on the SQL server used by TFS?

Answer (score 1):

Forgot to reply back on this. Sorry all. I looked at the exception and all the service accounts used by our TFS (which I didn't setup) and ensure it maps to the proper sql permissions. All in all, I granted our TFSService account SysAdmin rights on the sql box and that fixed the problem!

Ty

Comment: related to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/02f98a32-b82c-4ed7-88f6-7379257abcce/tf400975-failed-to-grant-tfs-job-agent-permissions-to-start-database-backups-on-sql-server-xxxxxx?forum=tfsadmin